# lock select for update but don't lock regular select

Tags: java, database, hibernate, locking

I am implementing a system in which I differentiate between `SELECT ...` and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

The regular `SELECT ...` is used to read entities, which are allowed to be in an 'incorrect' state (incorrect = might be updated moments after)

The `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is ALWAYS used to read an object with goal to edit it, so it should return the correct state of the object.

Now I'm trying to do the following:
whenever an object is read by the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement, lock other `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` queries on the same object. However, regular `SELECT ...` should still work.

Is there any way of doing this by using just predefined locks?
I looked at database isolation levels, but I don't think they are a part of my problem.

I'm using java, hibernate and an sql database.

Comment: You don't have to do anything? The `FOR UPDATE` will lock the necessary rows until you commit or rollback. No need to do explicit locking in Java. Also, when you say a sql database, do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: database product: mysql 

for update will lock the rows, but it will also lock them for a regular select, which is not my intention. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Select for update doesn't locks in MySQL. Its worked in Oracle, Postgres, MS SQL.